# javascript switch-case for 2 booleans

Tags: javascript, boolean, switch-statement, boolean-logic

I have 2 boolean values, boolA and boolB.
I want a single switch-case statement that takes each of the four possible combinations,
i.e. something like

```
switch(boolA boolB){
  case 0 0:
    [do something];
  case 0 1:
    [do something else];
  case 1 0:
    [do another thing];
  case 1 1:
    [do the other thing];
```

Basically I want the switch-case to interpret the two booleans as a single 2 bit number.

Update: I decided to just use normal if-else stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I'd do that.

But if you *really* want to, you can use `boolA + " " + boolB`:

```
switch(boolA + " " + boolB){
  case "false false":
    [do something];
    break;
  case "false true":
    [do something else];
    break;
  case "true false":
    [do another thing];
    break;
  default: // "true true"
    [do the other thing];
    break;
}
```

Or if you prefer numbers, `(10 * boolA) + boolB`:

```
switch((10 * boolA) + boolB){
  case 0:
    [do something];
    break;
  case 1:
    [do something else];
    break;
  case 10:
    [do another thing];
    break;
  default: // 11
    [do the other thing];
    break;
}
```

Both of those implicit conversions are guaranteed in the spec.

Answer (score 7):

The [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) docs refer to this method to achieve what you want by making the switch evaluate `true` and then putting logic in switch statements

```
switch (true) { // invariant TRUE instead of variable foo
    case a && b:
    //logic
        break;
    case a && !b:
    //logic
        break;
    case !a && b:
    //logic
        break;
    case !a && !b:
    //logic
        break;
}
```

I would just use regular if-else if logic to make things clearer.

Comment: The problem with doing it that way is that if the bools are function calls (presumably `boolA` and `boolB` aren't, but generalizing here), those calls are repeated until a matching case is found.

Comment: I wasn't sure it was even possible until I saw the docs on MDN, but good caveat.

Comment: :-) Yeah, JavaScript's `switch` is basically just syntactic sugar for `if...else if...else if`, unlike most other languages with syntax derived from B. In JavaScript, the cases can be expressions rather than constants, and they're evaluated in source order (no jump tables, etc. -- of course, if you use constants, an engine is free to optimize...).

Comment: when using node.js, the a&&b case is never true for some reason

Answer (score 3):

I decided to use

```
switch(parseInt(boolB.toString()+boolA,2)){
  case 0://neither
    [do something];
  case 1://boolA
    [do something else];
  case 2://boolB
    [do another thing];
  case 3://both
    [do the other thing];
}
```

which parses the booleans as bits in a binary number.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative implementation would be to not use a switch statement at all. You could create a javascript object mapping boolean values as keys to function objects.

```
var truthTable = {
    false: {
        false: falsefalseFunc,
        true: falsetruefunc
    },
    true: {
        false: truefalseFunc,
        true: truetrueFunc
    }
}
```

Where falsefalseFunc, falsetrueFunc, etc... are function objects. Then you can call it like:

```
truthTable[boolA][boolB]();
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6 Alternative combined with the [unary + operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus):

```js
switch (`${+boolA}${+boolB}`) {
    case "00": //logic
      break;
    case "10": //logic
      break;
    case "01": //logic
      break;
    case "11": //logic
      break;
  }
```